# background-position scss changes when building React application

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass, react-bootstrap

I am using sass (.scss files) in my ReactJs project with Twitter Bootstrap.

I am having am issue with the `.was-validated .form-control:invalid, .form-control.is-invalid` styling of button. The validation icon is placed with the `background-position` property.

This works as expected when running locally with the `npm start` command in the local React development server.
The css is loaded as:

```
background-position: center right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem);
```

The problem occurs when I build it for production, (`npm run-scripts build`). The css becomes this instead:

```
background-position: 100% calc(.375em + .1875rem);
```

It places the icons too far right after it changes. I have tried to override this in several different ways, but the css always changes to `100%` instead of `center right`.

Why does this happen and how do I make sure that `background-position` survives when I build the application?

Comment: try `calc(100% - 0.375em - 0.1875rem) 50%`

Comment: `background-position` only takes one or two arguments [as described here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp).

Comment: @Barthy no it doesn’t, not any more. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position#Values You just gave a perfect example of why w3schools should not be used as a reference ;-)

Comment: @TemaniAfif That works! I am still wondering why it changes, though. But at least I found a way to override the weird behaviour. Thank you.

Comment: you can also try `right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem) center`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks! I'll accept it if you post it as an answer :-)

Comment: I would wait for someone to give the correct fix that will prevent npm from doing this. If no answer, I will post my workaround as an answer.

Comment: @04FS exactly, I just wanted to set an example . Thanks for the hint!